# What should I do when I see a partially correct answer being the accepted answer?

Tags: discussion

I have seen multiple questions where the some of the answers are better than the accepted answer. For the user the accepted answer might work but it might not be the ideal/universal solution. For someone else it might fail.

Comment: That's the flaw of the accept mark. Don't take it as an undeniable proof... it's just the solution the OP chose. As to what to do... not much. Upvote/downvote the answers as usual, put a comment explaining why the accepted one isn't the best. Not much else to do

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Vote, comment or provide an alternative answer, if appropriate.

You have the ability to upvote right now and are not that far from the ability to downvote. You've only voted 7 times, total, according to your [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4593127/silentmonk?tab=topactivity). Vote more. Vote the good content up.

There are many questions with answers that have higher scores than the accepted answer. Users should be reading more than response and your votes will help the others filter to the top.

You also have the ability to post comments. Post a constructive comment on the partially correct answer. Point out why it is only partially correct and encourage the user to expand the answer. Their response isn't guaranteed, but your comment will help others evaluate the answer.

If you know a more complete answer, and it isn't already posted, provide one of your own. Competing answers aren't bad. Alternative solutions, especially to solutions that don't work completely, are encouraged.

Comment: Sure, thank you. I will take that into account. Are the answers listed in the decreasing order of upvotes?

Comment: There are three tabs (look above my answer), "Active", "Oldest" and "Votes". The default is by votes, I believe.